# VBScript how to detect hardware plugged in?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, script, vbscript

I tried searching but I can't seem to be find anything besides USB detection.  I want to make a script that detects when the speaker and microphone ports has a device plugged in.  Is this possible to do? Make the script run (some other stuff) when you plug in a headset for example.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to invoke a script by running a status query after calling **WMI Class Win32_bus** Class

```
On Error Resume Next 

strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Bus") 
For Each objItem in colItems 
 WScript.Echo("Availability: " + objItem.Availability); 
 WScript.Echo("Status: " + objItem.Status); 
Next
```

Read this page for more clarity : [Computer System Hardware Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389273(v=vs.85).aspx)